# ERROR running Appium command: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

The following error is showing when i try to connect to appium server.

ERROR running Appium command: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;\build-tools'

Below is my code:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, ""); //Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead.
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:/Appium/AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1/WishAndGreet.apk");
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:/Appium/AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1/TestApp");
    //capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.example.testapp"); //Replace with your app's package
    //capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".MainActivity"); //Replace with app's Activity
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```

Comment: i think it is showing the error based on the variables you set in the Path environmental variable ?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, finally i have got the solution of this problem. The mistake i made was very small.
Actually i was setting the Path of sdk platform tools folder in environment variable, but it must be the sdk root folder.

Use **D:\Android\android-sdk** instead of **D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools**.

Hope it will help. Vote up if it will. :)

Comment: correct way of setting ANDROID_HOME & related folder paths under it

https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/4ddbe49a67e5eb1b9c03